# Volvo Turn Signal Light Problem

Tags: electrical, volvo, lights, turn-signal, v70

My dad has an old Volvo V70 from 2001.

One of the blinkers (that yellow light that you turn on if you go left or right) is not working properly. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. We opened the hood and touched some wires etc etc we came to the conclusion that once we tighten the light it starts blinking and when we let go of it, it stops working. Or if we loosen the light as much as possible it starts blinking and once changed it stops.

So I'm wondering what could be the issue here and how can we fix it?

[image: Blinker1]

[image: Blinker2]

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly a poor connection within the bulb holder. You might be able to clean up the connections within the holder with a fine bit of sandpaper or "wet and dry", then adjust them with a tiny screwdriver to improve the contact, but it's probably easier to get a new unit...

Comment: Do like @Nick C says and replace if you can't revive it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this holder is called and therefore I can't find it on the internet to buy. Do you have any ideas how this is called ? Thnx

Comment: It's called just that - a bulb holder. You can find it by part number, for your V70 it should be 8662986. It should be stamped on the holder itself. It's a cheap part, but don't hurry with the buying, the contacts are probably just loose. Bend them outward with a screwdriver.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Found it, thanks for the part number !!